# CustomAnnotationView Changes to MKAnnotation in MapKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, annotations, mapkit, hide

Hello Everyone i am new in developing app for I-Phone I have stuck in the Custom ANNotationView in mapKit. When i load map first Time it shows correctly Custom View , But after scrolling map it become the red colored PIN (default annotation in MapKit). Kindly Help me . Thank You in advance.

I am using the following code in viewForAnnotation delegate

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:   (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {

            UIImageView *AvatarView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 30, 30)];

            AvatarView.layer.cornerRadius =AvatarView.frame.size.width / 2;
            AvatarView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            AvatarView.layer.borderColor =(__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:34.0/255.0 green:28.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]) ;
            AvatarView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            AvatarView.layer.zPosition=1;

    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView =
    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                        reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];





                // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.

        //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        if([[responseDataArray objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"thumbPath"]!=nil && [[[responseDataArray objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"thumbPath"] length]>0)
                                {


                            NSString *imgPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",WebSiteUrl,[[responseDataArray objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"thumbPath"]];

                            k++;

                            NSString* webStringURL = [imgPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
            NSString *imageName = [placeholderImageArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random() %placeholderImageArray.count)];
                                [AvatarView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];


    }
        [annotationView addSubview:AvatarView];
        return annotationView;
    }
    else
    {
        k=0;
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

I am using the following code to add Annotation

```
          MKPointAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            myAnnotation.coordinate = coord;
            myAnnotation.title = titleStr;
            myAnnotation.subtitle = @"Best bar in Town";


            [myLocation addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
```

It never goes to else part. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me to solve out this problem. A big thanks to You.